# Using super() In class that inherits from object

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, oop

I have seen a class like below:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
```

Why we may use `super` in a class that inherits from `object`? Is it the right approach?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to? It's best to consistently use `super` otherwise things start to go awry in multiple inheritance contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the right approach, because multiple inheritance makes it such that `MyClass` could end up in a different place in the MRO:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super(MyClass, self).__init__()
...
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print('Foo __init__!')
...         super(Foo, self).__init__()
...
>>> class Bar(MyClass, Foo):
...     pass
...
>>> Bar.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Bar'>, <class '__main__.MyClass'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Here `Bar` inherits from both `MyClass` and `Foo`, placing `Foo` before `object`. Because, `MyClass.__init__()` is doing the right thing and passing on the `__init__` chain via `super()`, `Foo.__init__` is correctly called:

```
>>> Bar()
Foo __init__!
<__main__.Bar object at 0x107155da0>
```